# Can the stream encoding change depending on the document version?

Tags: pdf, text, decode, encode

Hello StackOverflow community, I have a very interesting question about *Streams* in PDF files, I have 5 pdfs..

When I am decoding pdf *page content stream* , I split em by textBlocks, and then I wanna just convert them into regular string. **(I don't have a task to get text from PDF, the task requires that I parse this data stream and get text from it.)**

And this is what I am getting:

*1 document* **TEXT: Cyrillic alphabet**

`b'BT 11 0 0 11 0 0 Tm\n/TT2 1 Tf (!"#$%&\'\\(\\)*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\\\]^_`ab)\nTj ET'`

*2 document* **TEXT: This is a small demonstration .pdf file -**

`b'BT\r\n/F1 0010 Tf\r\n69.2500 688.6080 Td\r\n( This is a small demonstration .pdf file - ) Tj\r\nET'`

*3 document* **TEXT: overall number of doses in the series**

`b'BT 2.400000 213.686918 Td [(\x00o\x00v\x00e\x00r\x00a\x00l\x00l\x00 \x00n\x00u\x00m\x00b\x00e\x00r\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00s\x00e\x00s\x00 \x00i\x00n\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00s\x00e\x00r\x00i\x00e\x00s)] TJ ET'`

*4 document* **TEXT: Date of birth** in Romanian , Russian and English Languages

`b'BT 27.111811 391.343714 Td [(\x00D\x00a\x00t\x00a\x00 \x00n\x00a\x02\x19\x00t\x00e\x00r\x00e\x00 \x00|\x00 \x04\x14\x040\x04B\x040\x00 \x04@\x04>\x046\x044\x045\x04=\x048\x04O\x00 \x00|\x00 \x00D\x00a\x00t\x00e\x00 \x00o\x00f\x00 \x00b\x00i\x00r\x00t\x00h\x00:)] TJ ET'`

*5 document* **TEXT: Example text**

`b'BT\n0 Tr\n/F1 79.848503 Tf\n1 0 0.000000 -1 196.000000 874.080017 Tm\n[<0028>-0.839844<005B><0044>-0.847656<0050>-0.832031<0053><004F>-0.832031<0048>-0.847656<0003><0057>-0.832031<0048>-0.847656<005B><0057>-0.832031] TJ\nET'`

I know how to read first 2 documents , but I don't know the decode method.

I know how to read 3-4 documents , because I know that it uses unicode chars.*(but I mentioned that it don't works well with Cyrillic alphabet)*.

I don't know how to work with 5th doc , and I didn't understand how to decode this type of coding..

I would welcome any answer, any explanation and any advice.

Thank you.

Comment: The strings provided to the text operators use character codes, which are encoded according to the Encoding (for regular fonts) or CMap (for CIDFonts). So the first thing you need to know is if it's a Font or a CIDFont. Then you need to consult the Encoding or CMap which will give you the glyph in the font program to allow you to draw it. Note that none of this tells you what the character represents in human languages. If you are lucky the font or CIDFont will have a ToUnicode CMap which will allow you to lookup the Unicode equivalent of a character code. If not, then well too bad really.

Comment: Thanks , @KenS , I will try to figure that out.. appreciate your time, and thank you for your answer!

Comment: In essence, if you are only allowed to use the content streams (or the parts thereof which you call "textBlocks"), your task is impossible to solve in general. You need information from the font resources used, and even then - as KenS explained - you cannot always decode.

Comment: @KenS, but can I encode the string , that will be more useful I guess?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say you can 'encode the string'. The string is already encoded, you can decode it using either the Encoding or the CMap (see KJ's answer below) but there is no guarantee that will provide comprehensible information. The only reliable method is if the font has a ToUnicode; without that it's (mostly) just guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to use your challenger example 5 to show a basic way PDF font Look-up can be used to untangle some encodings, this is a relatively simple and common mix.

Your 5th example text is a very common CIDFont+F1 encoding remove the kerning (these are the small gap shifts between `< 16bit letters >` e.g. `>-0.839844<` means increase the gap by a small amount -= rightwards 0.8 sub units (an advance not measured in points) and we see starting  `[<0028>-0.839844<005B><0044>`

produces
[<0028><005B><0044><0050><0053><004F><0048><0003><0057><0048><005B><0057>]

This is a very common Cmap for that encoded text ***ignore the first entry***, since here without yours I am using another "Print to PDF" file that did not use that binary string <0028> for subset (so missing in this case).

Using this common look-up table we can translate using ASCII/ANSI bytes

```
stream
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin 12 dict begin begincmap /CIDSystemInfo << /Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (UCS) /Supplement 0 >> def /CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def /CMapType 2 def 1 begincodespacerange <0000> <FFFF> endcodespacerange 33 beginbfchar <0003> <0020> <000F> <002C> <0011> <002E> <0013> <0030> <0014> <0031> <0015> <0032> <0016> <0033> <0017> <0034> <0018> <0035> <0019> <0036> <001A> <0037> <001B> <0038> <001C> <0039> <0020> <003D> <0037> <0054> <003B> <0058> <0044> <0061> <0045> <0062> <0047> <0064> <0048> <0065> <004A> <0067> <004B> <0068> <004C> <0069> <004F> <006C> <0050> <006D> <0051> <006E> <0052> <006F> <0053> <0070> <0055> <0072> <0056> <0073> <0057> <0074> <0059> <0076> <005B> <0078> endbfchar endcmap CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop end end 
endstream
```

So the above is paired Cmap so we find first of pair and convert to second

<005B> <0078> x
<0044> <0061> a
<0050> <006D> m
<0053> <0070> p
<004F> <006C> l
<0048> <0065> e
<0003> <0020>
<0057> <0074> t
<0048> <0065> e
<005B> <0078> x
<0057> <0074> t

[image]

xample text is clearly correct so what is <0028>

Well from above table it is 8 more than `<0020> <003D>` thus should be <0045>

and blow me over sideways, it works too (but not always :-)

[image]

Overall it is an ex-streamly (pun:-) inefficient use of text as it would have been far simpler as `/F# Tf (Example text) Tj` and yet not been less readable by humans. All that kerning and 16bits for 8 + `>precision<` overheads just adds to the MagaFlops of carbon needed to read an accessible "Pretty" poorly justified Anglo-American text PDF.

HTML is far more efficient for wasting bytes.

Comment: Is there any way to implement this in python ?